# ¿Cómo cambiar el titulo de un Activity por un titulo con literales?

Tags: android, activity

A ver tengo esto:

**Strings.xml**

```
 <string name="title_activity_Item">Pedido</string>
```

**ItemActivity.java**

```
 setTitle(R.string.title_activity_Item +" "+pedido.getRef() );
```

**deveria imprimir algo así:**

> Pedido ref-44021

**en cambio me imprime algo así**

> 2131165340 ref-44021

porque? de donde sale ese numero? a caso es una referencia de memoria o algo así?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es que `R.string.title_activity_Item` no es otra cosa que un identificador numérico del recurso, para obtener su valor necesitas usar sus *getters*: `getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_Item);`

Precisamente, **[`getString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int))** debe recibir como parámetro ese identificador para devolverte la cadena.

Para más claridad en el código lo puedes hacer así:

```
String titulo=getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_Item)+" "+pedido.getRef();
setTitle(titulo);
```

Para más detalles puedes consultar [**Acceso a recursos**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources?hl=es-419)  en la documentación de Android.

Comment: muchas gracias!!!

Comment: De nada @sergipc88. Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.